# National characters in Open Tomato router and QNAP NAS shell

Tags: openwrt, localization, charset, qnap

I added my Country locale (pl_PL) to shell in Open Tomato based router Asus and QNAP NAS. Originally only en_US and en_EN locale where available.
Now it is possible to use it for example in vim-full editor, installed from Entware-ng. So now both on router and NAS, locale looks like this:

```
LANG=pl_PL.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="pl_PL.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=pl_PL.UTF-8
```

I send emails from router and NAS using msmtp command like this:

```
/bin/echo -e "Subject: Mail z routera ASUS\r\n\r\n<text with Polish characters>" |/opt/bin/msmtp --debug --from=default -t my_user@gmail.com,my_user@other.domain
```

Such emails are sending via gmail account, used as mail relay.

Below content of /opt/etc/msmtprc file:

```
defaults
tls on
tls_starttls on
tls_trust_file /opt/etc/certs/ca-bundle.crt

account default
host smtp.gmail.com
port 587
auth on
user my_account@gmail.com
password xxxxxxxx
from my_account@gmail.com
#logfile /opt/msmtp.log
```

The codepage for my language is Latin-8859-2.

The results are as follows.

- in iPad mail client, Polish characters are display properly both for Gmail account and for other.domain account
- in Linux Thunderbird Gmail account, Polish characters are display properly
- the same Thunderbird but other.domain account, strange symbols instead Polish characters
- mail read via Web page for other.domain, strange symbols instead Polish characters

All other sources emails are display properly on all platforms.

Probably I have to add something to config file or to msmtp command, to tell clients about codepage it have to use.
I call to other.domain admin but they dont know why Polish character are display not properly in they own system. Shame...
I dont know what to do. Any help?